# La subconsulta devolvió más de 1 valor. Esto no está permitido cuando la subconsulta sigue =,! =, <, <=,>,> =

Tags: sql-server

Me sale ese error al querer hacer este procedmiento almacenado, quiero guaradar varios  valores pero no se  como, creo que es  aqui SET  @IdE = (select ID from @IdentityOutput). EL procedimiento alamacenado  es de una tabla  maestro detalle ,hago una variable tipo tabla para guardar todos  los identity que  se generen pero  me  sale  ese  error

```
   /****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[analisis_insertar]    Script Date: 02/03/2021 07:55:58 a. m. ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER proc [dbo].[analisis_insertar]
@idusuario int,
@idpaciente int,
@iddoctor int,
@total decimal(11,2),
@detalle type_detalle_v READONLY,
@detallep type_detalle_pruebao READONLY
as
begin
DECLARE @idAnalisisInsertado  INT
declare @IdentityOutput table ( ID int  )
declare @IdE int
    insert into analisis (idpaciente,idusuario,iddoctor,fecha,total,estado)
    values (@idpaciente,@idusuario,@iddoctor,getdate(),@total,'Aceptado');
    
     SELECT @idAnalisisInsertado = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
    insert detalle_examen(idanalisis,idexamen,nomexamen,precio,estado)
    OUTPUT INSERTED.iddetalle_examen INTO @IdentityOutput (ID)
    select @idAnalisisInsertado,d.idexamen,d.nombreexamen,d.precio,'Pendiente'
    from @detalle d;
    
    SET  @IdE = (select ID from @IdentityOutput)
    
    insert detalle_prueba(iddetalle_examen,idprueba,resultado1,resultado2,resultado3,resultado4, valoresdereferencia)
    select @Ide ,dt.idprueba,dt.resultado1,dt.resultado2,dt.resultado3,dt.resultado4,dt.valoresReferencia
    from @detallep dt 
    
    end
```

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que pretendes lograr con esto? Creo que a tu pregunta le falta una explicación de cuál es tu objetivo, además de explicar a mayor detalle si hay alguna relación entre la información viene en los parámetros `@detalle` y `@detallep`

Comment: Estoy  realizando un sistema  para un laboratorio de  analisis clinicon.El procedimiento  almacenado es para una  tabla  maestro detalle que  a su  vez  esos  detalles  tienen otros  detalles .  los parámetros **@detalle **y **detallep@** son tipo tabla  en en **@detalle** trae  el idexamen, el nombre y precio y los inserta en la tabla  detalle_examen y  en **@detallep** estan datos  como idprueba,resultado y sus  valores  de referencia.

Comment: ¿Cómo se relacionan los registros de `@detalle` con los de `@detallep`? Es decir, puede ser una relación de uno a uno, o puede haber un campo que relacione un registro de `@detalle` con 0, 1 o varios registros de `@detallep`, o puede ser que no tengan relación. Si se relacionan, ¿es uno o varios campos?, y, ¿cuales son?

Comment: @jachguate el **@detalle** me trae el nombre del examen y el **@detallep** me  trae las pruebas  que le  corresponden a cada tipo de  examen . un analisis(tabla analisis) puede tener varios examenes (tabla detalle_examen) y un examen puede tener una  o varias pruebas(tabla detalle_pruebas)

Comment: @ja   por eso  requiero  de  todos los iddetalle_examen  para poder  depues insertar  las pruebas a sus examenes correspodientes. y los guardo  atraves  de**@IdentityOutput** y los traigo  atraves  SET  **@IdE = (select ID from @IdentityOutput)** pero  a la hora  de insertarlo  me  sa le  ese error

Comment: ¿qué campo relaciona esas tablas? Es decir, cómo sé que registros en `@detallep` se corresponden con el primer registro de `@detalle`? Quizás sea mejor que edites la pregunta e incluyas la definición de los tipos de las tablas de parámetro (`type_detalle_v` y `type_detalle_pruebao`).

Comment: @jachguate atraves  del idexamen

Comment: @jachguate quieres  ver que tipos de datos  tiene (type_detalle_v y type_detalle_pruebao)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### TL;DR;

Esta va a ser una respuesta un poco extensa, si no tienes tiempo de leerla completa, salta directamente a la sección de la solución

---

### Observaciones

Algunas observaciones sobre el planteamiento que has hecho en tu código de ejemplo:

- No hace falta que recuperes todos los Id's que se han asignado a la tabla detalle en una variable, están almacenados en la DB y puedes acceder a ellos sabiendo el `id` de la tabla maestra.
- Si quisieras recuperarlos, no puedes hacerlo en una variable escalar, por ejemplo una variable de tipo entero. Tendrías que declarar una variable tipo tabla y hacer un `insert/select`. Pero como ya he dicho, esto no hace falta.

Dado que tu pregunta no incluye un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), he preparado un ejemplo que me premita presentar una solución a tu problema.

---

### Estructura de ejemplo

Mi ejemplo se basa en la existencia de una estructura de tablas `encabezado`/`detalle`/`subdetalle`, según se puede apreciar en la siguiente imagen:

[image: ER encabezado/detlale/subdetalle]

Y los tipos de datos `TDetalle` y `TSubDetalle` que son tipos de dato tipo tabla, que sirven como parámetros para pasar los datos al procedimiento almacenado `pInsDatos` que es el que contiene la solución al problema planteado por el AP.

Debe notarse que **se ha simplificado la estructura a un solo campo de datos en cada tabla**, esto es para mantener el enfoque en el problema y que sea más fácil de entender la solución. Una vez se entienda, adaptar el código para que funcione con más campos debiera resultar trivial para el lector.

A continuación el script para crear estos artefactos en una base de datos:

```
create table encabezado (
    idEncabezado           int not null identity (1, 1) primary  key
  , nombreEncabezado       varchar(100) not null
);

create table detalle (
    idDetalle              int not null identity (1, 1) primary key
  , idEncabezado           int not null
  , nombreDetalle          varchar(100) not null
  , constraint fk_detalle_encabezado 
     foreign key (idEncabezado)
     references encabezado (idEncabezado)
     on delete cascade
     on update cascade
);

create table subDetalle (
    idSubDetalle           int not null identity (1, 1) primary key
  , idDetalle              int not null
  , nombreSubDetalle       varchar(100) not null
  , constraint fk_subdetalle_detalle
      foreign key (idDetalle)
      references detalle(idDetalle) 
      on update cascade
      on delete cascade
);

create type TDetalle as table (nombreDetalle varchar(100));
create type TSubDetalle as table (nombreDetalle varchar(100), nombreSubDetalle varchar(100));
go
```

Es importante notar que en la estructura de las tablas utilizadas como parámetros de entrada, cada registro de `@subdetalle` contiene el nombre del registro al que pertenece en la tabla `@detalle`

## Solución

Presento primero el código del procedimiento almacenado con el que se insertará la información a la estructura.

```
create procedure pInsDatos (
    @nombreEncabezado varchar(100)
  , @detalle TDetalle readonly
  , @subDetalle TSubDetalle readonly
)
as
begin
  declare @idEncabezado int;

  insert into encabezado (nombreEncabezado)
  values (@nombreEncabezado);

  set @idEncabezado = @@IDENTITY;

  insert into detalle (idEncabezado, nombreDetalle)
  select @idEncabezado, nombreDetalle
    from @detalle;

  insert into subDetalle (idDetalle, nombreSubDetalle)
  select detalle.idDetalle, sd.nombreSubDetalle
    from detalle
         inner join @subDetalle sd on sd.nombreDetalle = detalle.nombreDetalle
   where detalle.idEncabezado = @idEncabezado;
end
go
```

La lógica va más o menos de esta manera:

- Insertamos el registro de `encabezado`, obtenemos su `idEncabezado` valiéndonos de la función `@@IDENTITY` y lo almacenamos y en la variable `@idEncabezado`.
- Insertamos los registros de la tabla `detalle`, valiéndonos de una sentencia `insert`/`select` que tira de la variable `@idEncabezado` y de los datos que vienen en el parámetro `@detalle`
- Insertamos los registros de la tabla `subdetalle`. Para insertar estos registros, hacemos un join entre la tabla `detalle` y el parámetro `@subdetalle`, valiéndonos del campo `nombreDetalle` para relacionar los registros que vienen en el parámetro con cada registro almacenado en la base de datos. Esto nos permite recuperar directamente el `id` que el motor le ha asignado a cada registro de detalle, que es el que finalmente usamos para insertar en la tabla subdetalle. Mediante una clausula `where` nos aseguramos de traer únicamente los detalles que pertenecen al registro que se acaba de insertar en la tabla `encabezado`.

### Comprobación

Como parte del ejercicio, acompaño este script con el cual se llama un par de veces a la rutina de inserción, pasándole distintos valores en las tablas de parámetros:

```
declare @detalle TDetalle;
declare @subDetalle TSubDetalle;

insert into @detalle 
values ('uno'), ('dos'), ('tres');

insert into @subDetalle
values ('uno', 'uno.uno')
     , ('uno', 'uno.dos')
     , ('dos', 'dos.uno')
     , ('dos', 'dos.dos')
     , ('dos', 'dos.tres')
     , ('tres', 'tres.uno');


execute pInsDatos 'encauno', @detalle, @subdetalle;

delete from @detalle where nombreDetalle = 'dos';
delete from @subDetalle where nombreDetalle = 'dos';

execute pInsDatos 'encados', @detalle, @subdetalle;
go
```

Luego de ejecutar este, la consulta:

```
select encabezado.nombreEncabezado, detalle.nombreDetalle, subDetalle.nombreSubDetalle
  from encabezado
       inner join detalle on detalle.idEncabezado = encabezado.idEncabezado
       inner join subDetalle on subDetalle.idDetalle = detalle.idDetalle
```

Me devuelve el siguiente resultado (que es justo lo que esperaba ver):

```
nombreEncabezado nombreDetalle nombreSubDetalle
---------------- ------------- ----------------
encauno          uno           uno.uno
encauno          uno           uno.dos
encauno          dos           dos.uno
encauno          dos           dos.dos
encauno          dos           dos.tres
encauno          tres          tres.uno
encados          uno           uno.uno
encados          uno           uno.dos
encados          tres          tres.uno

(9 rows affected)
```

Comment: Muchas  gracias por  contestar y tomarte el tiempo. voy a leerla  y te comento

Comment: Muchas  gracias  por  su  ayuda. No me había  dado cuenta  de  que  no era  necesario  guardar todos los  identitys. Llevaba  varios  días  buscando  como solucionarlo y usted en un rato me pudo ayudar. Veo  que me  falta  mas lógica